# Tfs / AzureDevOps client libraries merge conflict resolution on AzureDevOps branches

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, tfs-sdk

I have written some c# code that aims to automate AzureDevOps merges between related tfvc branches, thereby attempting to keep them in sync (no baseless merges are performed).

This is achieved by relying on the client libraries located in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` NuGet packages.

The code uses the “Merge” method on the Workspace class within the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client`:

```
GetStatus status = workspace.Merge(sourceBranch,
                               destinationBranch,
                               vsFromChangeset,
                               vsToChangeset,
                               LockLevel.None,
                               RecursionType.Full,
                               MergeOptions.None); 

int numberOfConflicts = status.NumConflicts;
```

After the merge was completed I check the status of the NumConflicts field on the “GetStatus” object to determine if a merge conflict occurred.
If this is indeed the case, I stop the process and this particular merge needs to be resolved manually – i.e. merged within Visual Studio (I use VS2017 Prof).
This is not really a big deal as the productivity gained from the times that the automatic merge was indeed successful, is sufficient.

**The mystery that I am unable to explain is:**

In most cases when the client libraries merge indicates a merge conflict, and the merge is then done via Visual Studio, Visual Studio does it without any mention of a merge conflict. No problem what so ever.

It almost seems as if there is an extra level of “merge conflict resolution logic” within Visual Studio that enables it to do a more advanced type of merge conflict resolution as opposed to the client libraries?
But I am probably way off the mark here

That said, the usage of the `MergeOptions` Enum (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb171252(v%3Dvs.120))), is not entirely clear to me, so maybe that is the cause of the headache. Any source that elaborates more on the topic would be greatly appreciated. The MergeOptions is currently set to *none*, and that works for most cases.

Any ideas on what causes this behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this article can helps http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/20/tfs-api-part-19-merge

Comment: Thanks for the link Shayki! It does say something about the MergeOptions enum, but sadly it does not really explain the strange behavior I am witnessing.

Comment: Will you get same behavior if you disable "Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated" option in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hey Eddie, thanks for your suggestion. Of the bat, it thus seems like Visual Studio indeed contains some extra layer of logic that assists in merge conflict resolution.
I am actually surprised that nobody is commenting on this, in order to demystify the issue...
On the api side I do not see anything that sort of hints in the direction of “automatically resolve conflicts”

I have disabled the option you mentioned (“automatically resolve conflicts”) within Visual Studio and will try it as soon as the scenario occurs again. Keep you posted.

Comment: Only these options are available on the MergeOptions enum: 
    MergeOptions.AlwaysAcceptMine 
    MergeOptions.Baseless 
    MergeOptions.ForceMerge 
    MergeOptions.NoMerge 
    MergeOptions.None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by changing the mergeOptions parameter used in the Merge method on the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace class.

Using the merge options on the enum Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.MergeOptionsEx
**instead** of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.MergeOptions solved the issue for me.

I have now seen 80+ automatic merges work perfectly and no more of the previous erratic behavior. The merge command should look like this:

```
GetStatus status = workspace.Merge(sourceBranch,
                           destinationBranch,
                           vsFromChangeset,
                           vsToChangeset,
                           LockLevel.None,
                           RecursionType.Full,
                           MergeOptionsEx.None);
```

So the answer to my problem was found right at the bottom of a social.msdn [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b2c91eb-f874-4ce6-b1ef-af71805f4e13/tfs-api-merge-and-conflict-resolve-does-not-have-the-same-output-as-quottf-resolve?forum=tfsversioncontrol) by the unsung hero Mariusz Skoczylas. Many thanks!

The official documentation on MergeOptionsEx can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff736044(v%3Dvs.120))

Comment: I can confirm that I also hit this issue, and was able to mimic the behavior that "Visual Studio" was capable of. From what I'm reading about the "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.MergeOptionsEx" - it is a server instruction, and not a client instruction. Which could explain why Visual Studio (or TFS Server) has more logic in terms of handling this.